# Python strange TypeError: stream_changes() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

*Not to be mistaken with the similar post of the same name.* My code is quite simple. I am running this class in a main.py file and it is supposed to start running a timed thread, but I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
TypeError: stream_changes() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Here's my code.

```
class InnerTableThread:

    def __init__(self, service): # service called for an API verification
        self.f_stop = threading.Event()
        self.service = service
        self.stream_changes()

        return


    def stream_changes(self):
        print("Hello World")

        if not self.f_stop.is_set():
            threading.Timer(.3, self.stream_changes, [self.f_stop]).start() 

        return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`threading.Timer` takes [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) `(interval, function, args=None, kwargs=None)` so you're passing the arg `self.f_stop` to `self.stream_changes` which takes one argument `self` (which is automatically passed) but you're passing `self.f_stop` in addition.

Comment: You did it Mitchell!